# Angularjs eclipse plugin - modules not listed

Tags: angularjs, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to use angular js eclipse plugin:

https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started

I am behind corporate proxy.

My problem is intellisense is not working. I have read many tutorials for plugin installation but none of them is adressing the issue...

Any help please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that **AngularJS Eclipse is not very well installed**. Our **server which hosts the update site can be slow** and it seems that some people have a bad installation of AngularJS Eclipse.

If you are in this case, I suggest you that you dowload [local Eclipse update site](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/releases) and use it to install AngularJS Eclipse.